# As a web developer what should my 1st step for web site security?

Tags: security, web

I know how to build a site. But I don't know how to save it from a hacker.

Comment: Voted to reopen. While describing the whole IT security in an answer is of course impossible, that's not what the question asks. It's "what's the best way to start". There are many basic things that can be easily listed in the answer. It's a good question and something many people run into, knowing nothing about security guidelines before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spend ages on this, but assuming you're starting from scratch, I'd go with the following:

1. Read your framework/language security guide. For example if you're writing the web app in PHP/Symfony, read https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html and https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.php (this should be short and easy application of best practices / tweaking known settings)
2. Read anything relevant on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page). It may be hard to do all of it, but some sections to point out are: [Top 10 web issues](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Table_of_Contents), [Development guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Guide_Project), [Cheat sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets).
3. Keep applying what you learned and read more :)

Comment: Thanks, For the tips.